# VS2012 Custom Build Step - Treat Output As Content

Tags: build, visual-studio-2012, msbuild

I am currently migrating a reasonably large solution from VS2008 to VS2012. To date, this solution has been dependent on a command line build for several build steps, and I want to use the project system properly to execute these build steps.  I've been through the various options and decided that a custom build step makes sense in most of the VC++ projects that require it. The solution is a mix of C++, C# & VB.

These tasks include building Primary Inter-op Assemblies and processing output files using third-party utilities, where the input and the output are the same.

I've had some teething issues, but I'm mostly up and working with this approach. The remaining issue is one of deploying these additional outputs to dependent projects.

Consider this; I have a third-party component, which given an input of a.dll produces two outputs, a revised a.dll and a_util.dll.  When I have a project that is dependent on a.dll, I now need that project to pull a_util.dll in to it's output too.  I was hopeful that the "Treat Output as Content" field on the custom build step in VS2012 would help in this respect, but I'm going by the one-liner in the UI, I can't find any comprehensive documentation on this option.  In fact, the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev11.query?appId=Dev11IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28VC.Project.VCCustomBuildStep.Command%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version=v4.0%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version=v4.0%29&rd=true) just pretends this option doesn't exist.

If anyone can help explain this option, or an alternative approach, that would be great.

**EDIT**

At the moment, I am adding a BeforeBuild target to each dependent project to copy the additional outputs into that dependent project.  The problem with this approach (while it works) is one of maintenance. Unfortunately if a dependency of this type is missed, it results in a cryptic runtime error.

Comment: Is it possible to use ILMerge, so the third-party component transfer a.dll to revised a.dll? (combination of a.dll and a_util.dll)

Comment: @ccppjava - no, that's not an option... the util library is entirely native.

Answer (score 1):

[Here's a link to VS2013 documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee126324(v=vs.120).aspx) that says:

Treat Output As Content: This option is only meaningful for Windows Store or Windows Phone apps, which include all content files in the .appx package.